# matlab. labels to a pie chart

Tags: matlab, plot, pie-chart

I have a matrix X. In the first column there are 5 values which are integers from 0 to 4. In the second column there are values that I want to plot in a pie chart. How can I label the values in X(:,2) with the corresponding values from X(:,1) in the pie chart?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I understand this might do the trick:

```
clear all
clc

A = [0 3;1 1;2 5;3 6;4 5]; %// Generate dummy data

Labels = sprintfc('Row%d',A(:,1)+1) %// Generate appropriate labels and store in a cell array
```

Labels looks like this:

```
Labels = 

    'Row1'
    'Row2'
    'Row3'
    'Row4'
    'Row5'
```

and the pie chart:

```
pie(A(:,2),Labels)
```

[image]

Is this what you meant? You might want to take a look [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_plots/customize-pie-chart-labels.html) for more info about pie charts and ways in which to customize labels. For instance [sprintf](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sprintf.html) can be used to produce more complex labels. If you would like to know how please ask!

Comment: Hi @Yulia so is this what you were looking for?